# create a function with variable pointers parameters in C

Tags: c

how to create a function with variable pointers parameters that 
take any number of pointer and print it such as :

```
print("hello ","world ");
print("i'm ","adil"," blah "," blah");
```

result like that :

```
$ ./myprogramme
hello word im adil blah blah
```

I found stdarg.h but i don't know how to make it ?

Comment: va_args is what you need. There is a tutorial on the internet. Search for `va_args`

Comment: If you "found stdarg.h", why didn't you read how it works? There are thousands of demos, tutorials and manuals about it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you can create a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) using `stdarg.h`. Example from Wikipedia link,

```
#include <stdarg.h>

double average(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double sum = 0;

    va_start(ap, count); /* Requires the last fixed parameter
                            (to get the address) */
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        sum += va_arg(ap, double); /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return sum / count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost what you wanted, but it needed a NULL terminator

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void print (char *first, ...)
{
va_list argptr;
char *next;
    va_start (argptr, first);
    next = first;
    while (next) {
        printf ("%s", next);
        next = va_arg(argptr, char*);
        }
    va_end (argptr);
}

int main()
{
    print("hello ","world ", NULL);
    print("i'm ","adil"," blah "," blah", NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

But by adding a different argument, there's an easy answer anyway

```
printf("%s%s", "hello ","world ");
printf("%s%s%s%s", "i'm ","adil"," blah "," blah");
```